# is it possible to get SQL Server Reporting Services on Android?

Tags: android, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to create an Android application that show the sales report from SQL Server database using SQL Server Reporting Services. Is is possible to get the data from SQL Server into Android application? and if it's impossible, is there any alternative way to get the data from SQL Server and make the report into Android Application? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't technically get "Reporting Services to run *on* Android", there is no native Android component AFAIK comparable to the [Winforms ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724%28v=vs.90%29).

However, there are the [ReportViewer WebForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms%28v=vs.100%29) controls, which you can use in a .NET website. You should be okay viewing a site with those controls on your Android browser. If you use the 10.0.0.0 ReportViewer the [Browser Compatability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28v=vs.90%29) is decent, I've viewed reports on my Galaxy S with some success.

Comment: well, now I try to make my own report by create a store procedure to create the report into fact table..hope it works :)